# Runtime Error on Recursive Code

Tags: c++, recursion

Why this c++ code produce a `Runtime Error`?

anyone could help me?

https://ideone.com/trZwFD

```
int test(int a, int b)
{
int temp=1;
if (temp % b ==0 and temp % a ==0)
return temp;
temp++;
test(a,b);
return temp;
}
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: It is written in three languages?

Comment: yes, it's in java, and i re-write it for C++.

Comment: So it isn't written in three languages then.

Comment: it's not fair, to negative point to my question.

Comment: `test(a,b);` : Because the state is call unchanged and stack overflow by repeated calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each recursive call initializes `temp` to 1, so you never return from the method (assuming `(1 % b ==0 and 1 % a ==0)` is false for the given a and b), and always make another recursive call.

Comment: if we replace it with static int temp =1, is it true?

Comment: @user4249446 Is what true?

Comment: i means the recursion becomes true and end ?

Comment: temp %b will be non-zero for all values of a and b, and will give an exception for 0. So the if will never be true so you will always recurse => stack overflow if a and b non-zero, divide bv zero if a or b are zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int temp=1;
int test(int a, int b)
{
    if (temp % b ==0 && temp % a ==0)
    return temp;
    temp++;
    test(a,b);
}
int main(){
    cout<<test(2,3);
}
```

This code works well

Comment: How this can work ? the last line of the function should be `return test(a,b);` . The result is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give up recursion - what you want to do just don't justifies it.

```
int test(int a, int b)
{
     int temp = 1;
     while (temp % b == 0 && temp % a == 0)
        ++temp;
     return temp;
}
```